# R row indices as strings?

Tags: r, matrix, row, hashtable, dataframe

Given this dataframe:

```
       b  a  d c
    3 -2  1  3 2
    4  1  1  3 2
    5  1  1  3 2
```

Is it possible to rename the row indices like so?

```
         b  a  d c
    xxx -2  1  3 2
    yyy  1  1  3 2
    zzz  1  1  3 2
```

Essentially, instead of having numeric indices, I have strings as id's, like a hash table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
test<-data.frame(b=c(-2,1,1),a=c(1,1,1),d=c(3,3,3),c=c(2,2,2),row.names=c(3,4,5))

row.names(test)<-c('xxx','yyy','zzz')

> test
     b a d c
xxx -2 1 3 2
yyy  1 1 3 2
zzz  1 1 3 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, like this.

row.names(someDataFrame) = someVectorOfNames